# jquery: reappend <tr>s to <tbody> after removing them

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, tr, html-tbody

I have to buttons: **Add**, there I want to add s to my  (they come from a selected number) and **Reset** where want to remove those elements. I know I need to clone DOM elements after removing them, but how do I implement it. I´m relatively new to JS. Alternatively I can switch to a checkbox with this solution here: [with checkbox and cloning](http://jsfiddle.net/pvod0gam/1/) Any help appreciated - thks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>reprex jquery</title> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // what´s the value of the integer input?
        var no = 10; 
        let i = 1;
        $("#btn-add").click(function() {
            while (i <= no) {
                $("#tbl tbody").append("<tr><td><input></input></td><td><textarea></textarea></td></tr>");
                $("#tbl input")[i-1].setAttribute("name", "s" + i);                
                $("#tbl input")[i-1].setAttribute("value", i);
                $("#tbl textarea")[i-1].setAttribute("name", "c" + i);  
                ++i;
            }   
        });
    });
 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("#btn-remove").click(function() { 
            $("#tbl tr:gt(0)").remove();
        });
    });   
    </script>
 

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button class="btn" id="btn-add" type="button">Add</button>
        <button class="btn" id="btn-remove" type="button">Reset</button>
    </div>

    <table id="tbl">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>col1</th>
                <th>col2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not clear what is not working from your example. What have you tried so far and what is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add back your rows by checking the status of `i`. Since it's defined more globally, as you continue to use it, the value changes. Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  var no = 10;
  var i = 1;
  
  $("#btn-add").click(function() {
    if (i > 1) {
      i = 1;
    }
    while (i <= no) {
      $("#tbl tbody").append("<tr><td><input></input></td><td><textarea></textarea></td></tr>");
      $("#tbl input")[i - 1].setAttribute("name", "s" + i);
      $("#tbl input")[i - 1].setAttribute("value", i);
      $("#tbl textarea")[i - 1].setAttribute("name", "c" + i);
      ++i;
    }
  });

  $("#btn-remove").click(function() {
    $("#tbl tbody tr").remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <button class="btn" id="btn-add" type="button">Add</button>
  <button class="btn" id="btn-remove" type="button">Reset</button>
</div>

<table id="tbl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here you can see that `i` is changed in your `while`. You may need to reset it when the User clicks on "Add" button.

Comment: Many thks Twisty for your Bugfix. I was not aware that I loose my "i" when reusing the add button.